# I am using openpyxl to load data in template and i am getting warning in the destination file when i open

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to copy a csv file to excel template. The template file contains a pivot table and graph. When i open the template file I am able to open it without any issues or errors. But after i run the below code I am getting popup error in the destination file. I am missing anything here, which normally we need to do to handle excel.

```
wb_1 = xl.load_workbook(template_file)
ws_1 = wb_1['Workbook1']

with open('file_modified.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
    next(reader, None) #skip the headers in the csv file
    i = 2
    #ticket_count_asof_today = len(list(reader))
    for row in reader:
        for j in range(1, len(row)+1):
            if(j==1 or j==10):
                ws_1.cell(row=i, column=j).value = float(row[j - 1])
                #ws_1.cell(row=i, column=j).number_format = '0000000000'
            else:
                # writing the read value to destination excel file
                ws_1.cell(row=i, column=j).value = row[j-1]
        i +=1
        #print(row)

        #ws_1.append(row)
wb_1.save(destination_file)
wb_1.close()
```

THe error message is

`We found a Problem with some content in destination file. Do you Want us to try to recover as much as we can?If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes`

Answer (score 0):

You should change file format to .xlsx, because .csv format works with one sheet